# HTTP Method and REST URL for Returning Data that May Be Saved

Tags: rest, http, http-request

My application has a grid with a list of Car objects from a third party system

```
[{id: 1, make: "Ford", model: "Focus", ...},...]
```

The user can select a Car and use its data (after some transformation) to create a Car specific to my application. The app does this by filling in a form on another HTML page with the transformed 3rd party Car data and allowing the user to modify data as needed.

When the app makes the request to retrieve the transformed 3rd party car data, should that request be a HTTP GET (even though it transformed the data (in a repeatable way))? What should the URL be using REST standard formats? I don't think it should be `/third-party/car/{id}` since that is for returning the third party car as-is.

**Update**

Here's an overview of the architecture:
[image]

The diagram shows the URLs supported. The flow is:

1. Client requests HTTP GET `/third-party/cars/{id}/transform`, HTTP GET `/cars/third-party-cars/{id}` or some other URL. This is the URL in question.
2. My application receives the request and does the following:

   - Gets the 3rd party version of the car from the 3rd party DB
   - Transforms the 3rd party car in the CarService or ThirdPartyCarService to my application's version of a car (i.e. `Car`)
   - Populates and returns an HTTP form with `Car` data
3. The user then modifies the `Car` data as needed
4. The client either requests the `Car` data is saved via HTTP POST /cars or cancels.

Comment: You're overthinking this.  If the system is expected to provide a response to the form directly, just use a POST.  If you need to retrieve the car later, use a GET.  There's no such thing as a REST standard format for an URL.  If you want some guidelines anyway, look here: https://restfulapi.net/resource-naming/

Comment: Thanks Robert. Yes, the system will provide data to populate the form. The user can then either cancel out of the form or submit the form. Submitting the form will save the car data and I know that request should be a POST request. But you're saying that the request to get the transformed data for pre-populating the form should also be a POST?

Comment: I guess the retrieval of the transformed data is always going to be a GET.

Comment: Suggestions for the URI? After reading [restfulapi.net/resource-naming](https://restfulapi.net/resource-naming), I think this may be suitable as a controller archetype. For example, `http://localhost/third-party/cars/{id}/transform`. But it's a bit odd because the return value (mapped resource) is actually an unsaved car. Saved cars are returned by `http://localhost/cars/{id}`.

Comment: Why don't you just return the transformed car?

Comment: Yes, that's my plan. The URI would return the transformed car. Any suggestions on what the URI should be for getting the transformed car (that may or may not be saved by the user after getting)? Thanks for the help.

Comment: How do you retrieve a resource that was never saved?

Comment: The original resource (the un-transformed car) is saved in and retrieved from a third-party system. My system transforms the original resource into its version of a car. That's the URI (to get the unsaved transformed car) that I'm trying to figure out. After that, the user can then opt to modify and save the car OR can cancel saving the transformed car. I know the save URI would be a HTTP POST to /cars.

Comment: If you're returning the transformed car from `http://localhost/third-party/cars/{id}/transform`, why do you need another URL on your system to retrieve it?

Comment: The URL to retrieve a transformed car from the third party system only exists on my system. And that's the URL I'm trying to design. I could have it as HTTP GET `http://localhost/third-party/cars/{id}/transform` but I mentioned in a earlier comment that it is a bit odd b/c the return value is actually an unsaved car.  Another option that I thought about is HTTP GET `http://localhost/cars/third-party-cars/{id}` because a car from my system has a reference back to the third party car.

Comment: I have to admit, I'm confused enough where I don't think I'm going to be of any help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88473/discussion-between-james-and-robert-harvey).